# What is the AWS SDK library for signin in Cognito (from backend without using Amplify)?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have implemented user signup using @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider but not able to find the module or API from AWS SDK to implement sign in to cognito

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider` is the right lib for what you want to do.

```js
import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";
const client = new AWS.CognitoIdentityProvider({ region: "REGION" });

client.initiateAuth({
    ClientId: '...',
    AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: 'my_test_user',
        PASSWORD: '...'
    }
}, function(err, data) {});
```